# realizando una migración de un hosting a mi servidor local

Tags: wordpress

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Buenas realice una migración de un hosting a mi servidor local el cual es uniserverz a pesar de que el site web se ve correctamente no puedo entrar a la interfaz de administrador de manera local quiera saber si tengo que hacer alguna configuración adicional he intentado con las siguentes rutas https://localhost/site/wp-admin.php y https://localhost/site/wp-login.php. Pero me dice que la pagina no existe.

Comment: ¿Configuraste el archivo BD?

Comment: lo unico que hice fue modificar la direccion de wordpress y la direccion sitio antes de exportar la db de resto no realice una configuracion

Comment: Pero. ¿Estas corriendo el Wordpress local ?

Comment: si en un servidor local parecido a xampp

Comment: Y no te estas conectando fuera del local?

Comment: si también pero necesito que termine de funcionar de manera local por que tengo que hacer unas modificaciones y las puedo hacer directamente el hosting

Comment: cuales seria las configuracion del archivo .sql ?

Comment: 1. Importar la base de datos en tu servidor local.
2. Configurar el archivo PHP con tus credenciales.

Comment: lo primero ya lo hice cuando dices configurar el archivo PHP te refieres al wp-config.php si es ese tambien configure esta parte # Database Configuration
define( 'DB_NAME', 'site' );
define( 'DB_USER', 'root' );
define( 'DB_PASSWORD', '' );
define( 'DB_HOST', 'localhost' );
define( 'DB_HOST_SLAVE', 'localhost' );
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
define('DB_COLLATE', 'utf8_unicode_ci');
$table_prefix = 'wp_';

Comment: no se si es ese otro archivo

Comment: ¿Cual es el error que te aparece al abrir el sitio?

Comment: al abrir el sitio no me aparece ningún error el problema viene cuando quiero entras a la administracion del sitio

Comment: se refleja el siguiente mensaje.

Comment: No se puede acceder a este sitio web
La página localhost ha rechazado la conexión.
Prueba a:

Comprobar la conexión
Comprobar el proxy y el cortafuegos
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo que esta ocurriendo es que esta mal migrado y apuntas a la BBDD remota y el FTP puede que también.

Si tienes el backup de los ficheros y de la BBDD montar el sitio en local debe ser sencillo.

1.- Ubicas los archivos en la carpeta de localhost elegida.

2.- Con PHPMyAdmin importas la BBDD en una base de datos local.

3.- Editas el archivo wp-config.php y cambias lo que sea diferente (Nombre de la base de datos, usuario de la base de datos local, password de la base de datos local, host de la base de datos local (normalmente localhost))

4.- Con PHPMyAdmin abres la base de datos y busca la tabla llamada "wp_options" y abrela.

5.- En el campo "option_name" tiene que poner "siteurl" y el "option_value" debes cambiarlo a "http://localhost/carpetadondetengaslosficheros" (importante!!: sin barra al final)

6.- En la misma tabla ("wp_options") busca otro "option_name" llamado "home" y su "option_value" haces lo mismo, lo cambias a "http://localhost/carpetadondetengaslosficheros".

7.- Una vez hecho estas cosas abres un navegador con "http://localhost/carpetadondetengaslosficheros/wp-login.php" te logueas y vas a Ajustes>Enlaces permanentes

Alli te fijas que opción esta seleccionada y seleccionas otra diferente y le das a guardar y luego vuelves a seleccionar la que tenias seleccionada primero y le das a guardar otra vez.

Y ya debería funcionar.